# Remove default tableView contents in UI Interface

Tags: ios

This is an incredibly simple question that I some reason cannot figure out how to do.  I added a tableview to my view, and it is populating with default contents.   How do I remove these default contents in the interface?  (I am aware this is not populating when the app is ran, I just find this an eyesore to look at).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove default tableView contents in UI Interface because it is default contents. It shows as an example, that's why.